# Injecting IHubContext into my background service for SignalR in .NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, background-service, asp.net-core-signalr

i have a hub class

```
       public class MyHub : Hub {
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
       
    public MyHub(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

when i try to inject Ihubcontext and run the app i get:  unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContex

```
public class NotificationService : BackgroundService
{
private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _hubContext;
private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
private int lastProcessedNotificationId = 0;
public NotificationService(IHubContext<MyHub> hubContext, AppDbContext dbContext)
{
_dbContext = dbContext;
_hubContext=hubContext;

        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
              
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessageToAll("Test");
    
            }
        }
    }
```

i expect to be injected like in my controller it works

Comment: how does your Program.cs looks like ?

Comment: app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/MyHubRoute");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });   services.AddSignalR(options =>
            {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong package. In your project, you should use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` package, instead of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`.

You need to uninstall the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` package, since signalr is build-in feature in asp.net core. You don't need to add any packages. You can use it like below in the .cs file namespace.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
```

And  for J.Memisevic's comment, we want to check how you register the background service.

**Something like**

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<NotificationService>();
```